# VS 2017 CMake does not recognize macros

Tags: c++, cmake, macros, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to define a couple of custom `#define` in cmake but for some reason VS recognizes them as defined macros but checking if it is defined `#ifdef` does not work.

Example:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(StormEngine VERSION "0.0.0")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

if (WIN32)
    add_definitions(-DWIN32_BUILD)
elseif(WIN64)
    add_definitions(-DWIN64_BUILD)
endif()

if (WIN32 OR WIN64)
    add_definitions(-DWIN_BUILD)
endif()

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(StormEngine ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

**updated CMakeLists.txt**

*Note: the problem still presists even after changes seen below.*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(StormEngine VERSION "0.0.0")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

if (WIN32)
    add_definitions(-DWIN32_BUILD)
    add_definitions(-DWIN_BUILD)
endif()

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(StormEngine ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   std::cout << "main called..." << std::endl;
#ifdef WIN_BUILD
   std::cout << "Window Build" << std::endl;
#endif
   return 0;
}
```

output should be:

```
main called...
Window Build
```

actual output:

```
main called...
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing a `"` after `Window Build`

Comment: that was my bad. I adjusted the post. That is not present in my actual code. I typed the example out instead of copy/paste

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I pretty much just followed the tutorial located https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/

Comment: I don't think WIN64 is a CMake variable. cmake --help-variable WIN32 says ***``True`` on Windows systems, including Win64.***

Comment: With that said I am not sure why your add_definitions is failing. `WIN_BUILD` should still be defined even if `WIN64` is not valid.

Comment: @drescherjm you are correct. This was just a simple test to ensure definitions was working but in my project VS does not handle defines properly. I wonder if it is a setting or something

Comment: It'd be helpful if you looked at the cmake's output.  1) CMakeCache.txt and 2) The actual VS project files.  I've had issues with 2017 not regenerating the cache when it should, among others.

Comment: @zzxyz agreed. I'd go further and just delete the existing CMakeCache.txt file.

Comment: @zzxyz I cleaned the CMake project and that as you suspected updated the `#ifdef`. This has solved my problem. Please put this as an answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you read e.g. [this reference about CMake variables that describe the system](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-that-describe-the-system), there is no `WIN64` or `WIN` variables.

Use [`WIN32`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_WIN32.html) to detect Windows (both 32 and 64 bit).

Comment: This is correct. As I recently stated in a comment this was simply a test and I have since changed the code. The issue is still in effect where VS recognizes that `WIN_BUILD` is a macro but does not update the `#ifdef` correctly

Comment: What's wrong with using the built-in macros `_WIN32` and `_WIN64`? Those are defined automatically by CL.